# Phalcon Not accepting CASE query

Tags: php, sql, phalcon

I am trying to execute an raw query in phalcon using the case statement. When i try to run the same query directly I am getting the result But when I use the phalcon query model getting the following exception. Its not accepting the WHEN statement.

query: SELECT COUNT() AS COUNT,COLUMN4,COLUMN2,COLUMN5,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW( ) , TIME) <=90 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS TIME1 FROM newjs.TABLENAM WHERE COLUMN1=:VALUE: AND COLUMN2 IN({TYPE:array}) AND COLUMN2 NOT IN ({skip:array}) GROUP BY COLUMN4,COLUMN2,COLUMN5,TIME1

> exception 'Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Exception' with message 'Syntax error,
> unexpected token WHEN, near to ' DATEDIFF(NOW( ) ,  `TIME`) <=90 THEN
> 0 ELSE 1 END AS TIME1 FROM newjs.TABLENAME WHERE COLUMN1=:VALUE: AND
> COLUMN2 IN({TYPE:array}) AND COLUMN2 NOT IN ({skip:array}) GROUP BY
> COLUMN4,COLUMN2,COLUMN5,TIME1', when parsing: SELECT COUNT(*) AS
> COUNT,COLUMN4,COLUMN2,COLUMN5,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW( ) ,  `TIME`)
> <=90 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS TIME1 FROM newjs.TABLENAME WHERE WHERE
> COLUMN1=:VALUE: AND COLUMN2 IN({TYPE:array}) AND COLUMN2 NOT IN
> ({skip:array}) GROUP BY COLUMN4,COLUMN2,COLUMN5,TIME1 (256)' in
> /Users/Pankaj1/Sites/branch/contactengine/models/Contacts.php:488\nStack
> trace:\n#0 [internal function]:
> Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query->parse()\n#1 [internal function]:
> Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query->execute()\n#2
> /Users/Pankaj1/Sites/branch/contactengine/models/Contacts.php(488):
> Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Manager->executeQuery('SELECT COUNT(*)...',
> Array)\n#3
> /Users/Pankaj1/Sites/branch/contactengine/controllers/ContactController.php(532):
> PhalconRest\Models\Contacts->executeRawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*)...',
> Array)\n#4 [internal function]:
> PhalconRest\Controllers\ContactController->getContactsCount('9397643')\n#5
> [internal function]:
> Phalcon\Mvc\Micro\LazyLoader->__call('getContactsCoun...',
> Array)\n#6 [internal function]:
> Phalcon\Mvc\Micro\LazyLoader->getContactsCount('9397643')\n#7
> /Users/Pankaj1/Sites/branch/contactengine/index.php(307):
> Phalcon\Mvc\Micro->handle()\n#8 {main}

Please Suggest how to executing the query which has the CASE statement.

I even try using the query building. That is also giving the me the same exception.

Edit:
I did tried with If statement and that is working. Still wanted to know if the case statement works with phalcon?

Comment: Please provide your query.

Comment: SELECT COUNT() AS COUNT,COLUMN4,COLUMN2,COLUMN5,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW( ) ,  TIME) <=90 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS TIME1 FROM newjs.TABLENAME WHERE WHERE COLUMN1=:VALUE: AND COLUMN2 IN({TYPE:array}) AND COLUMN2 NOT IN ({skip:array}) GROUP BY COLUMN4,COLUMN2,COLUMN5,TIME1

Comment: Please don't dump query here. Edit your question and post your full code.

Comment: You have `WHERE WHERE` in your query which is making it fail.